# German names for windows groups?

Tags: windows-10, user-groups

I'm looking for windows groups names in german language, due I have to configure something with accesschk on Windows 10 Pro. I get errors which tell me that the names are not valid.

Maybe here are some german speakers which could know and translate these technical terms ?

These groups I couldn't translate:

> Authenticated Users = Hauptbenutzer ?
>
> Interactive = ?

This are the commands I needed to run :

```
accesschk -w -s -q -u Users "C:\Program Files"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Users "C:\Program Files (x86)"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Users "C:\Windows"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Everyone "C:\Program Files"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Everyone "C:\Program Files (x86)"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Everyone "C:\Windows"

accesschk -w -s -q -u "Authenticated Users" "C:\Program Files"

accesschk -w -s -q -u "Authenticated Users" "C:\Program Files (x86)"

accesschk -w -s -q -u "Authenticated Users" "C:\Windows"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Interactive "C:\Program Files"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Interactive "C:\Program Files (x86)"

accesschk -w -s -q -u Interactive "C:\Windows"
```

Comment: Doesn't accesschk take SIDs? Those are usually fixed.

Comment: Perhaps SIDs would work too. It's okay it seems to work I found the names, within groups as users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### These groups I couldn't translate:

> Authenticated Users = Hauptbenutzer ?
>
> Interactive = ?

You can use the Microsoft [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx) to look up terminology translations:

Authenticated Users is Authentifizierte Benutzer

Interactive is Interaktiv

Interactive Users is Interaktiver Benutzer

Users is Benutzer

Everyone is Jeder

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I miss some groups in my OS, Jeder, Interaktiv, Authentifizierte Benutzer, at least the last one might be Administratoren ?

Comment: Administrators is Administratoren

Comment: are there language-neutral group names that I could use? I have a script that uses icacls to change file permissions. And it just failed in other pc because it is in German. This answer gave me a quick fix (Jeder instead of Everyone). But I would like to have my script actually portable.